# Get title of front window in carbon

Tags: macos, window, macos-carbon

I am writing a program to sit in the background on osx 10.6, listen to keystrokes and record them, grouping them by window title.  (No, I am not writing malicious software.  I do not need this program to be sneaky in any way, I just want to have a safety net for when I have typed a huge email and then accidentally refresh the page (APPLE-R) instead of opening a new tab (APPLE-T))  I have already found apple's EventMonitorTest example for the keystroke capturing code, now I just need to find the "key window" title.

Does anyone know where I can find examples for this kind of functionality?  Thank you!

Comment: Reddit.com and most sites have the same problem. Don't they know localstorage exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

1. You could use the [Accessibility API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html) (though of course keep in mind that 64-bit Carbon does not support this)
2. You could use the [CGWindow functions](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) introduced in Leopard

I suspect the first option will be easier to do this with, since the CGWindow API is somewhat low-level and treats all windows (application windows, menu bars, dock icons, etc.) more or less equally.